# When are files closed in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume

I'm running into few issues when writing to HDFS (through flume's HDFS Sink). I think these are caused mostly because of the IO timeouts but not sure.

I end up with files that are open for write for a long long time and give the error "Cannot obtain block length for LocatedBlock{... }". It can be fixed if I explicitly recover the lease. I'm trying to understand what could cause this. I've been trying to reproduce this outside flume but have no luck yet. Could someone help me understand when such a situation could happen - A file on HDFS ends up not getting closed and stay like that until manual intervention to recover lease?

I thought the lease is recovered automatically based on the soft and hard limits. I've tried killing my sample code (I've also tried disconnecting network to make sure no shutdown hooks are executed) that is writing to HDFS to leave a file open for write but couldn't reproduce it.

Answer (score 2):

We have had recurring problems with Flume, but it's substantially better with Flume 1.6+.  We have an agent running on servers external to our Hadoop cluster with HDFS as the sink.  The agent is configured to roll to new files (close current, and start a new one on the next event) hourly.

Once an event is queued on the channel, the Flume agent operates in a transaction manner -- file is sent, but not dequeued until the agent can confirm successful write to HDFS.

In the case where HDFS is unavailable to the agent (restart, network issue, etc.) there are files left on HDFS that are still open.  Once connectivity is restored, Flume agent will find these stranded files and either continue writing to them, or close them normally.

However, we have found several edge cases where files seem to get stranded and left open, even after the hourly rolling has successfully renamed the file.  I am not sure if this is a bug, a configuration issue, or just the way it is.  When it happens, it completely messes up subsequent processing that needs to read the file.

We can find these files with `hdfs fsck /foo/bar -openforwrite` and can successfully `hdfs dfs -mv` them then `hdfs dfs -cp` from their new location back to their original one -- a horrible hack.  We think (but have not confirmed) that `hdfs debug recoverLease -path /foo/bar/openfile.fubar` will cause the file to be closed, which is far simpler.

Recently we had a case where we stopped HDFS for a couple minutes.  This broke the flume connections, and left a bunch of seemingly stranded open files in several different states.  After HDFS was restarted, the recoverLease option would close the files, but moments later there would be more files open in some intermediate state.  Within an hour or so, all the files had been successfully "handled" -- my assumption is that these files were reassociated with the agent channels.  Not sure why it took so long -- not *that* many files.  Another possibility is that it's pure HDFS cleaning up after expired leases.

I am not sure this is an answer to the question (which is also 1 year old now :-) ) but it might be helpful to others.